# Remoção da tag [linguagemformal-autômatos]?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

A tag [linguagemformal-autômatos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linguagemformal-aut%c3%b4matos) é uma tag com apenas três perguntas:

- [Como transformar uma gramática livre de contexto em um autômato de pilha?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243105/64969)
- [Expressão regular para reconhecer linguagem: palavras que não contenham "bbab"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241285/64969)
- [Alguém poderia me ajudar com essa linguagem formal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208540/64969)

E, sim, eu sou autor de [67%](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x+from+x+%3D+0+to+2%2Fsqrt(3)) das perguntas.

Ela também não tem recomendações de uso nem tampouco wiki de tag.

Também não vejo ela agregando muito conteúdo no site. Creio que seja melhor ter no lugar dela [teoria-da-computação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teoria-da-computa%c3%a7%c3%a3o), que abrange esse conteúdo de linguagens formais também. Assim o assunto não estaria pulverizado de maneira desnecessária.

Comment: Por mim tudo bem, podes substituir a tag `linguagemformal-autômatos` pela tag `teoria-da-computação`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feito. A tag já era.

Comment: Beleza xD Eu estava esperando um maior posicionamento/dar uma semana, mas acho que essa é a vontade da comunidade mesmo =)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Tags que têm poucas perguntas muitas vezes não fazem falta, ainda mais quando são redigidas de forma fora do padrão (sem o hífen entre `linguagem` e `formal`). De vez em quando eu elimino tags assim silenciosamente.